# How to push extra columns to resulted data

Tags: html, angularjs

am getting data from database and binding to table , but i want to add extra columns to resulted data ,
am getting name value from database  , but from ui i want to push extra column city to table

view

```
<table>
   <thead>Name</thead>
   <thead>City</thead>
   <tr ng-repeat="r in result">
      <td>
         {{r.Name}}
      </td>
      <td>
         {{r.City}}
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

angular

//actually this data coming from database , am hard coded

```
$scope.rvm = [{
        Name: 'M',
    },
    {
        Name: 'B'
    }
]
$scope.result = $scope.rvm;
$scope.result.push({
    City: "Hyd"
}, {
    City: "Guntur"
});
```

i tried this but  city values adding to next row .but i want to add in table correct format

Comment: do you push city manually or it is input control ?

Comment: manually , actually i have to dates binding from data base , i want calculate days between those then i want to save that result days in another column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try:

```
$scope.result = [];
var city = "hbd"; // what ever value you want
angular.forEach($scope.rvm, function (value, key) {               
            $scope.result.push({
                Name: value.Name,
                city : city
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing two additional objects to the array. So you end up with an array of 4 elements. The first two contain only a name. The last two contain only a city. That's not what you want. What you want is to add a property to the existing objects in the array:

```
$scope.result[0].City = "Hyd";
$scope.result[1].City = "Guntur";
```